# Visualisation Attentions Transformer-based Architecture

Tags: visualization, transformer-model

I have a transformer based architecture, specifically I have both an encoder using Vision Transformers and a decoder using Language Models based on Transformers.
We know that Transformers have a specific attention mechanism named 'Self-attention'.
I was wondering, having a trained model (I am using PyTorch), what should I visualise to understand what part of the input is the most important? I suppose I have to visualise the weights of the Self-attention layer to understand what is more important for the prediction.

Here I report a part of the model that is explicative:

```
ViTLayer(
          (attention): ViTAttention(
            (attention): ViTSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=False)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=False)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=False)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): ViTSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): ViTIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): ViTOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          )
          (layernorm_before): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (layernorm_after): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
   )
```

I suppose I should visualise the `VitSelfOutput` Linear layer weights to understand what part of the input image is useful for the prediction,
am I right?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for the help,
S